# Elegant margin in listing environment?

Tags: listings, margins

If you look at how this example below is rendered in StackExchange, you see a nice margins around the hello world code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
```

I would like to obtain the same in LaTeX, but it seems an hard one... I would like the same result as in Stack Exchange around `3em` top and bottom and `1em` left and right. The `framexleftmargin` does not really work because it does not indent the frame and it looks quite ugly.

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={16cm, 24cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\lstset{
  language=c,
  backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},
  aboveskip=3em, % Not working
  belowskip=3em, % Not working
  % framexleftmargin=1em,
}

\begin{document}
\section{Some code}
 
Lorem Ipsum:

\begin{lstlisting}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to draw a frame, because if you set `frame=none` the margin commands don't work. So you need `frame=single` and `framerule=0pt` to draw a frame that isn't visible. Now you can set the margins within the frame and then you have indent the whole frame, to align it with the text:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\lstset{
  language=c,
  backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},
  frame=single,
  framerule=0pt,
  framextopmargin=3ex,
  framexbottommargin=3ex,
  framexleftmargin=1em,
  xleftmargin={\dimexpr 1em+3pt},
  linewidth={\dimexpr \linewidth-3pt}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Some code}
 
Lorem Ipsum:

\begin{lstlisting}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]